# C++ SDL_FreeSurface crash in destructor

Tags: c++, vector, sdl, destructor

I have a class `Block` which calls `SDL_FreeSurface(surface)` in the destructor. In the `main()` when I create an instance of Block, the object functions properly but when I used it in another class `Control` ,which has `vector<Block> block_vector` as a data member, the program crashes when I add an instance of `Block` into the `block_vector`. I narrowed down the problem which is the destructor of the `Block` when calling `SDL_FreeSurface(surface)`. Does adding objects to the vector have anything to do with is? What is the problem?

```
 class Block{

public:

    Block(int x, int y);
   ~Block();


    void Load_Image(MediaFunctions &M_Functions);

    void SetPosition(int x, int y);

    void BlitBlock(SDL_Event &event, MediaFunctions &M_Functions, SDL_Surface *destination);


    bool DetectionNames(SDL_Event &event, MediaFunctions &M_Functions, SDL_Surface *destination);

    bool DetectionHours(SDL_Event &event, MediaFunctions &M_Functions, SDL_Surface *destination);

    bool return_error();



private:


    SDL_Surface *block_surface_names;
    SDL_Surface *block_surface_hours;

    SDL_Surface *block_names_detected;
    SDL_Surface *block_hours_detected;

    SDL_Rect     block_rect_names;
    SDL_Rect     block_rect_hours;


    bool error;

    };


    //the problem
    Block::~Block(){


    SDL_FreeSurface(block_surface_hours);
    SDL_FreeSurface(block_surface_names);

    SDL_FreeSurface(block_hours_detected);
    SDL_FreeSurface(block_names_detected);

    }



    //when doing this 
    void Control::HandleEvents(SDL_Event &event, MediaFunctions &M_Functions){

if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){

    if( event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_a ){

            //append a block instance
            BlockVector.push_back(Block (Block(100,100)));
            BlockVector.at(block_index).Load_Image(M_Functions);

            block_index++;

    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Are you verifying that the instance of Block is valid?

Comment: when i remove `SDL_FreeSurface` from the destructor, program works fine.

Comment: @Unit978: Yes, but in that case it probably leaks `SDL_Surfaces` (this is not a good thing).

Comment: that is why i need to know why calling SDL_FreeSurface in the destructor is crashing the program when i add it to the vector.

Comment: As Mankarse said, we need to see your code to identify the problem.

Comment: the code has been set up

Comment: Have you tried running it with debugging on in the destructor? Does the constructor allocate the objects and verify that they're not NULL? Is the `Block` instance not NULL?

Comment: Mankarse's suspicions were correct.  You need to define the copy constructor and the assignment operator.  See the links in his comment.

Comment: very well, ill see where this leads to

Comment: how will copy constructor and the assingment operator fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you insert one of your Block objects into the vector, a copy is made.  Since you didn't provide a copy constructor, the compiler generated copy constructor is used.  The compiler generated copy constructor will simply copy your pointers over. It won't copy the actual SDL surfaces.

That means that your original Block object, and the Block object that is inserted into your vector both have pointers to the same SDL surfaces.  When the lifetime of one of those Block objects ends, the destructor is called, which frees the SDL surface.  Now the other Block object has a dangling pointer, and when its lifetime ends, and the destructor is called, you call SDL_FreeSurface on a dangling pointer.

This is almost certainly what is causing your crash.  That's why you need to follow the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), and properly implement both a copy constructor, and an assignment operator.  The implementation is up to you.  In most cases, I would recommend doing a full, deep copy of your objects.  But for such heavyweight objects as SDL surfaces, I would recommend you look at implementing some kind of reference counting mechanism, or use `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter that calls `SDL_FreeSurface` instead of `delete`.

Comment: The crash occurs when the object is created in the vector. the destructor isnt even called yet. i added a copy constructor and the crash still occurs